# Should tires always be changed in axle pairs?

Tags: tires

It's my mum's car and she basically has no clue about the history. Just pays the figure on the service invoice every year.

I inspected all four tires and noticed the following:

```
NSF - Antares DOT 4319

NSR - Antares DOT 4319

OSF - Antares DOT (? see pic)

OSR - Chengshan DOT 1614
```

[image: OSF - not a DOT code format I understand - is it saying 2014?]
*I'm not familiar with the DOT format on the pictured OSF tire. Is it saying 2014 inside that indented oval window?*

In other words, the tires on the N/S of the vehicle are a matching pair with same date code, whereas the tires on the O/S don't match each other or the tires on the N/S!

Maybe there was a puncture early in the life of the OSR so that's why it's a different brand. But why would you ever rotate tires leaving you with this arrangement?

Do we have reason to be unhappy with whoever has been servicing her car? Perhaps this is a sensible rotation given some set of conditions?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Anyone know about the DOT code though?

Answer (score 1):

The [date code](https://www.tires-easy.com/blog/tire-dot-date-code/) is read as the first two digits are the week of production, with the second two being the year.

So:

- 4319 = 43rd week of 2019
- 1614 = 16th week of 2014

No clue about the tire in the picture.

Comment: Yeah this is the type of date code I'm familiar with. But I come across tires all the time which don't conform to this format

Comment: If they are US DOT compliant, they should use this code structure. I don't know for sure what goes on in other countries, but assume there are other ways this date is annotated. As for your imaged tire, you might want to check around the tire (inside/outside sidewalls) if there's another patch which might have the right code.